# How to clean up without reinstalling?

Tags: uninstall

Every few years I come to a point where my Ubuntu gets rather bloated, as it is filling up with a lots of packages that I never use. So the goal is to roll the list of installed packages back to what Ubuntu ships by default and then reinstall everything I feel missing (as that's faster then trying to sort out which packages are unused). How do I do that? How can I find out if a given package is part of the default install or not?

Or simply put: Where can I find a complete list of packages that Ubuntu installs by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu in a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox). Then run:

`dpkg --get-selections >installed_packages.txt`

Your installed packages are listed in the installed_packages.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

`gtkorphan` can be used to remove packages that have been orphaned/have no dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install gtkorphan
```

Be careful as some top level packages such as `ubuntu-standard` and `linux-headers` will also be displayed and should not be removed. `gtk-orphan` also allows you to purge left over configuration files from removed packages.